# How to get koa-router query params?

Tags: node.js, koa2

I haved used axios.delete() to excute delete in frontend ,code like below

```
Axios({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url:'http://localhost:3001/delete',
    params: {
        id:id,
        category:category
    }
})
```

And I used koa-router to parse my request in backend ,but I can't get my query params.

```
const deleteOneComment = (ctx,next) =>{
    let deleteItem = ctx.params;
    let id = deleteItem.id;
    let category = deleteItem.category;
    console.log(ctx.params);
    try {
        db.collection(category+'mds').deleteOne( { "_id" : ObjectId(id) } );
}
route.delete('/delete',deleteOneComment)
```

Could anyone give me a hand ?

Comment: isnt it router.del()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, I think you misunderstood `context.params` and `query string`.

I assume that you are using `koa-router`. With `koa-router`, a `params` object is added to the koa `context`, and it provides access to `named route parameters`. For example, if you declare your route with a named parameter `id`, you can access it via `params`:

```
router.get('/delete/:id', (ctx, next) => {
  console.log(ctx.params);
  // => { id: '[the id here]' }
});
```

To get the query string pass through the HTTP body, you need to use `ctx.request.query`, which `ctx.request` is koa request object.

Another thing you should be aware with your code is essentially, a http delete request is not recommended to have a body, which mean you should not pass a `params` with it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ctx.query` and then the name of the value you need.

For instance, for the given url:

`https://hey.com?id=123`

You can access the property `id` with `ctx.query.id`.

```
router.use("/api/test", async (ctx, next) => {
    const id = ctx.query.id

    ctx.body = {
      id
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

per [koa documentation](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/request.md) ctx.request.query